# How to detect on a WCF Service that a client just got disconnected?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm handling the channel faulting and closing event as below

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
                    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
                    UseSynchronizationContext = false)]

 OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += Channel_Faulted;
 OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += Channel_Closed;

 private void Channel_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       //perform Something
 }

 private void Channel_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        //perform Something
 }
```

The binding info is as below.

```
NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);
tcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(48, 0, 0);
tcpBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
tcpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
```

The event handlers get hit when i gracefully end the client by closing/aborting the proxy but the event handlers do not get called when i kill the client process through the Task Manager or shutdown the system on which the client is running. What am i doing wrong here? Any code example to handle this situation will be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an XY problem?  If your service *instancing* is `PerCall` it won't matter because connections will open and close for each method call to the service.

Service faulting only occurs as a result of using a WCF conduit.  Killing the process will sever the underlying TCP connection.  Unless your server is in the middle of using the channel it won't fault.

What I generally like to do with my *per-session* WCF services is mark them `IDisposable` then handle any cleanup tasks in the `Dispose` regardless of graceful termination.

Comment: The instancing is single instance. I've added more info about the service. Sorry for being vague. I guess i'm asking what's wrong with my solution here.

Comment: @vinny no worries.  I think my answer still applies

Comment: In this situation do i need to keep pinging the client to see if they're still alive? since there is nothing to dispose of.

Comment: @vinny You could.  It depends on your application.  _Does_ your server need to call back into the client unexpectedly? Is your server opening explicit connections to the client?  If the only time the server needs to send something is the result of a client calling into the server during the same connection, then "no" I would not see the need to.

Comment: Yeah, the server needs to callback to the client at random times based on user response. It might be an hour or two days which is why I wanna know if the connection drops.

Comment: @vinny that was not evident in your question.   In order to call back into the client, the server needs to open a channel to the client first.   If you terminated the client the server will know about it the next time it tries to invoke it.   Anyway, keeping a idle connection open for days isn't particularly efficient